# meaning of SIP frames

Tags: sip, wireless, codec

I was reading a book about voice over IP in wireless networks and at some point the author is talking about $k_1$ frames included within a SIP message? I don't know what that means. In case of VoIP telephony, which frames are included within a SIP message?

The book is

Voice over IP in Wireless Heterogeneous Networks
H. Fathi
S.S. Chakraborty
R. Prasad

Comment: Perhaps quoting a section of the book could provide more context?

Answer (score 0):

Given that SIP is a strictly control plane protocol (as opposed to the media plane), the question seems a category error: SIP doesn't include any frames at all.

Or: SIP describes how to initiate, change, and tear down "sessions", long-running relationships between multiple entities described by some *other* protocol. Usually, SIP controls the session, SDP describes the protocols used by the session, and other protocols - RTP, typically - send media (voice, text, etc) between the entities.

Comment: true but SIP can be used over UDP or TCP

Comment: @Bob SIP is in fact transport agnostic: it can run over any transport protocol, theoretically. The transport that some agent happens to use might in turn run on a protocol defined in terms of frames (say, Ethernet), but SIP has no idea about that lower protocol.

Comment: I think that the author of the book meant the number of packets needed for a SIP msg, in order to compute the probability of retransmission.